# Javascript string parsing (for Slack integration)

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

In javascript, how best to parse the following **field**:value pairs out of this type of string? Keep in mind that the number of field:value pairs will vary.

"**title**:This is the title **description**:This is the description **requestor**:Joe Bradley"

Would love it if the result was an array/object (or whatever) of field names and corresponding field values that I could then work with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this by using reducer and a combination of split and indexOf.

```js
const str = "TITLE:This is the title DESCRIPTION:This is the description REQUESTOR:Joe Bradley";

let lastRecordedKey = "";
const res = str.split(" ").reduce((acc, cur)=>{
    if(cur.indexOf(":") === -1){
      acc[lastRecordedKey] += ` ${cur}`;
    }else{
      const words = cur.split(":");
      lastRecordedKey = words[0];
      acc[lastRecordedKey] = words[1];
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with a regular expression to get the parts, and loop to make an array or object :

```js
var str = "title:This is the title description:This is the description requestor:Joe Bradley"

var obj = {}, arr = str.split(/\s*(\w+)\s*:/)

for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i += 2)
  obj[arr[i - 1]] = arr[i]

console.log( obj )
```